# Linux command 'sz' failed to transfer file to Windows

Tags: linux, permissions

I used to use `sz` in another Linux host and it worked well. I downloaded files successfully, but this time when I use 'sz' in another Linux host, things go like this:

Although the File Transfer window appears, the terminal tells me that there's `No permission to write on the specific folder`.

[image: No permission to write on the specific folder.]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message. Your user is unable to write to the location on disk where its trying to. Try changing the directory the file is saved to on your local computer. Your home directory is a.good candidate, but also try /tmp

Comment: I have tried both and I even tried to set the folder of local host shared to everyone, but all ended up with "No permission to write on the specific folder". I want to know how to grant "permission to write" to the remote Linux host, but thank you for trying to help anyway!

Comment: When I look at your screenshot, the "File Name" is not a valid filename.  Maybe the OS is having difficulties with the name of the file.  I've not used this protocol for many, many years, but can you use "cat /cs108/download-chrome.....exe | sz -"  and then rename the resultant sXXX.sz to chrome-64.exe or what have you?

Comment: Holy yeah! I just simply rename that file as "chrome64" and try "sz" again, and things are done after renaming the file. The reason of previous transfer failure must be the bad file name although shell told me that it was the permission. You have really helped me out! Thank you!